# VS 2013 ReportViewer only showing first row

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, dataset, reportviewer

I am trying to user ReportViewer to run a report with a dataset filled from a datagridview.  I can populate the dataset but I when I run the report, it's only showing the first row.  I have done countless hours of searching on this and nothing seems to work.

- I have make sure =First(...) was removed from my report field expression
- I think the problem has something to do with the XML for the dataset but I am not very familiar with it.
- This is just an example, once I figure this out I can transfer my knowledge to my actual project.

Here's what I have:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    dgv.Columns.Add("FirstName", "First Name")
    dgv.Columns.Add("LastName", "Last Name")
    dgv.Rows.Add("John", "Smith")
    dgv.Rows.Add("Jane", "Doe")
    createData()

End Sub

Private Sub createData()

    Dim dt As New DataTable("namesTable")

    dt.Columns.Add("FirstName")
    dt.Columns.Add("LastName")

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv.Rows
        dt.Rows.Add(row.Cells(0).Value, row.Cells(1).Value)
        MsgBox(row.Cells(0).Value & " " & row.Cells(1).Value)
    Next
    MsgBox(dt.Rows.Count)

    DataSet1.Tables.Add(dt)

    MsgBox(DataSet1.GetXml)

    Dim DSReport As New ReportDataSource()
    DSReport.Name = "DataSet1"
    DSReport.Value = DataSet1.Tables("namesTable")

    ReportViewer.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingMode.Local
    ReportViewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "Report1.rdlc"
    ReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
    ReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(DSReport)
    ReportViewer.LocalReport.Refresh()
    ReportViewer.RefreshReport()

End Sub
```

As I'm adding to the dt, my MsgBox message shows me, correctly, my two names.
The MsgBox dt count is 2 so my two names added.

The Dataset XML shows this, which I think is the problem but I don't know how to fix it:

[DataSet1 XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mvbdr.jpg)

The report then shows:

[ReportViewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpyTs.jpg)

Thanks for any help, this is driving me crazy.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your datasource is not right, why not just use your dataset that you just created. This code works for me:

```
        ReportViewerHeader.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
        Dim rds As New Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportDataSource("namesTable", dt)
        ReportViewerHeader.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Report1.rdlc"
        ReportViewerHeader.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds)
        ReportViewerHeader.DataBind()
        ReportViewerHeader.LocalReport.Refresh()
```

Comment: It has to be converted first from what I understand.  I tried it anyway and got the message "Value of type 'WindowsApplication1.DataSet1' cannot be converted to 'Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource'

Comment: I added some code from a working program, it should get you close, but you will probably have to adjust it.

Comment: Thanks, Chuck. "DataBind" does not exist for me, what did you import for that, if anything?  If I just comment out the DataBind, it runs but the ReportViewer is completely blank.  If I add RefreshReport() at the end of the code it tells me that the data source instance has not been supplied for data source DataSet1 .